# How to change vboxmanage Default machine folder for root user

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Ahoj, I have user bobot which is able to use vboxmanage controlvm in linux cli and this user works well for switching off and on virtual machines. For testing reasons I want to do the same with root user but this is not working apparently because Default machine folder for user bobot and user root are not the same:

```
vboxmanage list systemproperties | grep forder (bobot):
Default machine folder:          /opt/boo/data
vboxmanage list systemproperties | grep folder (root)
Default machine folder:          /opt/boo/hacklab
```

So this means root is not able to restore machines because VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named...

Question is how to change Default machine folder for user root from /opt/boo/hacklab to /opt/boo/data

Thank you very much

/// found it after intensive googling
vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder /opt/boo/data